# Google App Engine : Cursor Versus Offset

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Do you know which is the best approach for fetching chunks of result from a query?

## 1.Cursor

```
q = Person.all()
last_cursor = memcache.get('person_cursor')
if last_cursor:
    q.with_cursor(last_cursor)
people = q.fetch(100)
cursor = q.cursor()
memcache.set('person_cursor', cursor)
```

## 2.Offset

```
q = Person.all()
offset = memcache.get('offset')
if not offset:
   offset = 0
people = q.fetch(100, offset = offset)
memcache.set('offset', offset + 100)
```

Reading the [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors), it seems that Cursor does not add the **overhead** of a query offset.

Comment: It would be interesting to see some measurements on this :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While it's hard to measure precise and reliably, I'd be astonished if the cursor didn't run rings around the offset approach at soon as a sufficiently large set of Person entities are getting returned.  As [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_fetch) say very clearly and explicitly,

> The datastore fetches offset + limit
>   results to the application. The first
>   offset results are not skipped by the
>   datastore itself.
>
> The fetch() method skips the first
>   offset results, then returns the rest
>   (limit results).
>
> The query has performance
>   characteristics that correspond
>   linearly with the offset amount plus
>   the limit.

I'm not sure how it could be any more explicit: **O(offset + limit)** is the big-O performance of fetching with an offset.  If overall (say over multiple scheduled tasks) you're fetching a million items, 1000 at a time, when you fetch the last 1000 (with offset 999000) the datastore does **not** skip the first 999000 (even though fetch does not return them), so the performance impact will be staggering.

No such caveat applies to using cursors: fetching resumes exactly where it left off, without having to repeatedly fetch all the (possibly many) items already fetched along that cursor in previous queries.  Therefore, with performance **O(limit)**, elapsed time should be arbitrarily better than that you can obtain with an offset, as long as that offset gets sufficiently large.

Comment: What would you consider to be a "sufficiently large set of Person entities"? 1,000? 10,000? 100,000? Thanks!